# What are the clear proofs from the Islamic corpus that the crucifixion or the death of Jesus never took place?

Tags: quran, hadith, death, prophet-isa, jews

In the Quran there seems to be only one verse i.e.4:157, that denies the crucifixion of Jesus. Even in that verse the denial is about what the Jews who claimed.

Even though there are hundreds of thousands of hadiths, none seems to deny categorically what the News Testament teaches about Jesus' crucifixion, death and resurrection.

Crucifixion, death and resurrection of Jesus Christ are so central and widespread among various Christian sects early on, including in the seventh century Arabia. Is there any clear evidence that denies the crucifixion, death and resurrection of Jesus Christ in the Islamic texts, both in the Quran and Hadiths?

Comment: Please be aware that the Qur'an is the word of Allah and it's the whole truth as per the Muslim belief. Secondly be aware that none of 'Isa's companion could witness a crucification since all of them were hidden after 'Isa's capture by the Jews therefore it is logical that the Qur'an addresses the Jews false witnesses since they lied in other to spread falsehood and fear among the Christians about 'Isa's crucification. So the Christian belief of the crucifixion is based on hearsay of their "enemies".